# problem when open with live server (visual studio code) : err_internet_disconnected?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am newbie with visual studio code and meet this problem. I code a very simple program and trying to open it by live server and tried to check it by ipad, iphone or some mobile.

But, my problem is, when I changed my code, each time I changed it, and opened my code, it said to me that I had this problem : ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED and when I open it by dimensions (ipad or iphone), it seems very different as the design.

As you can see in this picture [image: picture about my problem]

I must reload it every time when I change the code. Here is when I reload, very ok.

[image: picture when I reload the code]

Could you please help me to solve this problem ?
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented on your code but I am lacking sufficient reputation to comment.
Here are the things You can try Maybe One can fix Your problem:

1. Clear browser Cache.
2. Check localstorage and clear it also and try again.
3. Try to stop and restart Live server And Vs code.
4. Turn on full reload of Live Server [See It here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjtw4.gif)

If that doesn't solve the problem Then Notify Me